# Twilio: How to set up a time dependent call forward

Tags: twilio, forwarding

I run a company that has two locations, 1 in France and 1 in Australia. We do a lot of business with American companies so we set up a US number with Twilio. Currently, that number is forwarded to our French number permanently.

However, I would like to forward it to the Australian number at certain times of the day - e.g. for those hours that France is asleep. Kinda creating a follow the sun phone number.

I don't really know where to start in Twilio so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that in order to use twilio, your application returns XML to twilio in response to a call being made, so for example, if you wanted to forward a call all the time, your application would need to return XML similar to this (C# pseudo code):

```
Response.Write("<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
Response.Write("    <Response>");
Response.Write("        <Dial>");
Response.Write("            <Number>");
Response.Write("                205-444-5555");
Response.Write("            </Number>");
Response.Write("        </Dial>");
Response.Write("    </Response>");
```

Since you want to vary the number dialed, depending on the time of day, you need a bit of back-end server code to generate different XML, depending on the time of day, so your code would look something like this instead:

```
Response.Write("<xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
Response.Write("    <Response>");
Response.Write("        <Dial>");
Response.Write("            <Number>");
if (**your conditional time logic goes here**)
   Response.Write("                444-444-4444");
else
   Response.Write("                444-555-5555");
Response.Write("            </Number>");
Response.Write("        </Dial>");
Response.Write("    </Response>");
```

now depending on the language you use, the code will vary a bit, and their are several helper libraries to make some of this logic easier, but at its simplest, its pretty simple to do what you want: when twilio calls your number, twilio will request a page from your website that needs to return simple XML to twilio to tell it what to to. The code that produces that XML can be written in any back-end language that you want, and can vary the content of that XML using any conditions that you want.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Just wanted to add that we have a Nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.TwiML/) that makes it a bit easier to generate the TwiML shown in the annswer, so you wouln't need all of the response.writes and magic strings.